# p4 changes equivalent for P4Java

Tags: java, perforce, p4java

I want to get the CLs that are part of all intermediate builds between two build labels. That can be achieved on the command line using :

```
p4 changes "DEPOT_DIR_STRUCT/...@>BUILD_LBL_1,@<=BUILD_LBL_2"
```

Is there a P4J equivalent of this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind. Got it.

This can be done using the `IServer.getChangelists(...)` method.

First argument should be set to `-1` for complete list of CLs.

The second argument for this method, i.e. the `List<IFileSpec>` should be created using the `FileSpecBuilder.makeFileSpecList(...)` method with the parameter as `"DEPOT_DIR_STRUCT/...@>BUILD_LBL_1,@<=BUILD_LBL_2"`.

The other parameters should be set to `null, null, true, true, false, true` in that order.

I later encountered [this](http://forums.perforce.com/index.php?/topic/3346-p4-changes-i-showing-incorrect-changes/) problem with certain build labels. So if you encounter a similar situation, try setting the `includeIntegrated` parameter to `false`